# Cómo forzar scroll vertical en sentido inverso en un div determinado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estoy intentando averiguar cómo hacer un div que se mueve verticalmente en el sentido habitual (el rojo) y otro que haga lo propio pero en el sentido inverso (el azul) al hacer scroll. Adjunto el ejemplo con el que estoy trabajando a ver si alguien puede "arreglarlo".

```js
var recorrido = $(window).scrollTop()
var altura = $(document).height()
var avance = ($(window).scrollTop() / ( $(document).height() - $(window).height() ) ) ;
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
$('#down_up').css('bottom','avance');
});
```

```css
body{margin:0;}
#up_down{width:40%; background-color:red;position:absolute; left:3%; top:10%; }
#down_up{ width:40%; background-color:blue; position:absolute; right:17%; bottom:90%; }
.carrusel{ width:100%; height:500px; background-color:orange;}
.carrusel2{ width:100%; height:500px; margin-top:100vh;background-color:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="up_down">
<img class="carrusel">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
</div>
<div id="down_up">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso resuelto adaptando este código: http://jsfiddle.net/5UUtV/1/ a lo que deseaba; ahora mi único problema es que no consigo adaptar correctamente el asunto del "resize".

```js
function myFunction() {
                  alert($(".panel").length);
}
var winHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#invertido").css('bottom',$(window).height());
 $("#regular").css('top',$(window).height());
 $(".carrusel2").css('margin-top',$(window).innerHeight());
    $("body").height($("#content").height());
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function (event) {
 $(".carrusel2").css('margin-top',$(window).innerHeight());
});
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    $("#invertido").css('bottom',($(window).scrollTop()*-1) + $(window).height());
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#regular{width:37%; background-color:red; position:absolute; left:6%; z-index:1000; padding-top:50vh;  }
#invertido{ width:37%; background-color:blue; position:fixed; right:20%;  z-index:1000; padding-bottom:50vh; }
.carrusel{ width:100%; height:500px; background-color:orange;}
.carrusel2{ width:100%; height:500px;background-color:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<div id="regular">
<img class="carrusel">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
</div>
<div id="invertido">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
<img class="carrusel2">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: considera marcar tu respuesta como correcta ;)